# How to understand functor in \g x -> fmap ($) g x

Tags: haskell, functor, map-function

I am a beginner to Haskell. I know that the function `fmap` takes two arguments (`(a->b) -> f a ->`) and returns a functor (`f b`), but I cannot understand the following lambda expression

```
*Main> :t \g x -> fmap ($) g x
\g x -> fmap ($) g x :: (t -> a -> b) -> t -> a -> b
```

where is the functor?

Btw, I have tried several similar expression with different brackets, which give different results:

```
*Main> :t \g x -> fmap ($) (g x)
\g x -> fmap ($) (g x) :: Functor f => (t -> f (a -> b)) -> t -> f (a -> b)

*Main> :t \g x -> fmap $ g x
\g x -> fmap $ g x :: Functor f => (t -> a -> b) -> t -> f a -> f b
```

I don't understand this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From

```
\g x -> fmap ($) g x :: (t -> a -> b) -> t -> a -> b
```

we have

```
g            :: t -> a -> b
x            :: t
fmap ($) g   :: t -> a -> b
fmap ($) g x :: a -> b
```

To find the functor, it suffices to write the type of `g` as the type-level application `F X` for some `F` and `X`.

We have

```
t -> a -> b    =    (->) t (a -> b)
```

hence, `F = (->) t` and `X = (a -> b)`.

Therefore, the `fmap` call works in the `(->) t` functor. We need to think to `t -> a -> b` as a value of type `a -> b` "wrapped" under the functor `(->) t`.

Now, we have

```
($) :: (a->b) -> a -> b
-- which means
($) :: (a->b) -> (a -> b)

g   :: F (a->b)
fmap ($) :: F (a->b) -> F (a->b)
fmap ($) g :: F (a->b)
-- i.e.
fmap ($) g :: t -> (a->b)
```

Comment: Link to base source https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1003

Answer (score 4):

First, we have, as you said,

```
fmap :: Functor f 
     => (  a    ->   b   ) -> f a -> f b
($)  ::  (t->s) -> t -> s
g    ::                       f a
     ~                        f (t->s)
-----------------------------------------   a ~ (t->s) ~ b
fmap ($) g ::                        f b
           ~                         f (t->s)
```

and then this is applied to an `x`... but only *functions* get applied to arguments:

```
fmap ($) g :: Functor f        => f    (t->s)
           ~  Functor ((->) c) => c -> (t->s)
           x                   :: c
----------------------------------------------   f ~ ((->) c)
fmap ($) g x                   ::      (t->s)
```

and indeed `((->) c)` is a functor. So the application to an `x` is what selects a specific Functor type, the Functor of functions.

Putting it all together,

```
--                         g             x
\g x -> fmap ($) g x :: (c -> (t->s)) -> c -> (t->s)

-- compare with
        fmap ($)     ::  f    (t->s)  -> f    (t->s)   -- Functor (f ~ ((->) c)
        fmap id      ::  f    q       -> f    q
        id           ::  r            -> r
```

Indeed `($)` is just a more specialized `id`, and `fmap id === id`, by the Functor Laws. The type just gets more specialized because of all the extra arguments / instantiations giving more context to it.